# How to deserialize complex data types (mixed elements) in ABAP simple transformations

Tags: xml, abap-st

I am working on an xml simple transformation logic, and I came across the following XML structure:

```
<PARENT>

<CHILD_1> some text start <CHILD_2> content </CHILD_2> some text continued </CHILD_1>

</PARENT>
```

Normal transformation procedure fails, expecting the end of the element <CHILD_1>.:

```
                  <tt:cond check="exist(child_1)">
                      <child_1 tt:value-ref="$ref.child_1"/>

                      <tt:cond check="exist(child_2)">
                        <child_2 tt:value-ref="$ref.child_2" />
                      </tt:cond>

                  </tt:cond>
```

Is it possible to deal with this situation in simple transformations in ABAP, and if yes, how? I would like to avoid XSLT usage...

Cheers,
Ferenc

Answer (score 0):

I guess that Simple Transformation doesn't handle XML text nodes natively, you need to use workarounds.

For instance, with my test program below (only the important part is posted), I get the whole `CHILD_1` content, exactly as it is, i.e.= `<CHILD_1> some text start <CHILD_2> content </CHILD_2> some text continued </CHILD_1>`, in XSTRING type with UTF-8 encoding.

After that, you may parse the contents of `CHILD_1` with the ABAP XML Library you want, e.g. SXML.

The use of the type `XSDANY` is a key part of the XML Libraries to work directly with XML content (you can find explanations in the official ABAP documentation):

```
TYPES:
  BEGIN OF ty_transfo_result,
      child_1 TYPE xsdany,
  END OF ty_transfo_result.
transfo_name = create_transfo( concat_lines_of( sep = |\r\n| table = VALUE string_table(
          ( `<?sap.transform simple?>                               ` )
          ( `<tt:transform                                          ` )
          ( `xmlns:tt="http://www.sap.com/transformation-templates">` )
          ( `  <tt:root name="PARENT"/>                             ` )
          ( `                                                       ` )
          ( `  <tt:template>                                        ` )
          ( `    <PARENT>                                           ` )
          ( `      <CHILD_1 tt:value-ref="PARENT.CHILD_1"/>         ` )
          ( `    </PARENT>                                          ` )
          ( `  </tt:template>                                       ` )
          ( `                                                       ` )
          ( `</tt:transform>                                        ` ) ) ) ).
DATA(transfo_result) = VALUE ty_transfo_result( ).
DATA(xml) ='<PARENT>'
        && '<CHILD_1> some text start <CHILD_2> content </CHILD_2> some text continued </CHILD_1>'
        && '</PARENT>'.
CALL TRANSFORMATION (transfo_name)
    SOURCE XML xml
    RESULT parent = transfo_result.
cl_abap_unit_assert=>assert_equals(
    act = transfo_result
    exp = VALUE ty_transfo_result(
            child_1 = cl_abap_codepage=>convert_to(
                `<CHILD_1> some text start <CHILD_2> content </CHILD_2> some text continued </CHILD_1>` ) ) ).
```